# How can I do a easy image replace with opacity transition in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I've created a code which is changing the current image after 3 secconds. Now the new current image is getting displayed without a smooth opacity effect. This looks bad and I want to change that. I want to do it with VueJS but wasn't apple to do it.

At the moment picture 1 is replaced with picture 2. But I would want that picture 2 replaces picture 1 with a transition. From vueJS I found the following:

```
        .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
            transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
        }

        .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */
        {
            opacity: 0;
        }
```

and that you can use it within a  component, but I didn't quite understand that.

Current code:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    images: [
        'img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg'
    ],
    currentImage: 'img1.jpg',
    counter: 0,
    loaded: true
},
created() {
    let self = this;
    setInterval(function () {
        self.loaded = !self.loaded;
        self.currentImage = self.images[self.counter++];
        if (self.counter > self.images.length - 1)
            self.counter = 0;
    }, 3000);
}
});
```

template html code:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="col-avatar">
        <div class="prot-image img-fill-container">
            <transition name="fade">
                <img class="avatar" v-if="loaded" :src="'/caro/' + currentImage"
                     alt="Avatar">
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sheyu2rn/

Comment: Can you share your `<template>` (html) codes?

Comment: Okay, there we go :)

Comment: where have you added `.fade-enter-active` , `.fade-enter` classes in html?

Comment: well, in a style.css -- I just used basic vueJS syntax. Not in components where I is a scoped css element.

Comment: yes, so you need to add/remove the classes dynamically to see the transition when adding the image.

Comment: I've updated my question. This works quite okay. But the transition is like way to slow. The opacity is changing von 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1 back. Each time needs 0.25 s - so the process takes 0.5s -- But it needs about 3-4 secconds.

Comment: Can you share a live demo ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or else), it will be a great help to figure out the problem. maybe, the time delay is for Asynchronous JS cause you are using `setInverval()`

Comment: Okay I did, it's in my question :)

Comment: Try changing `.fade-enter` -> `.fade-enter-to`

Answer (score 0):

Change `.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to` to `.fade-enter-to, .fade-leave-to`:

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-enter-to, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */
{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this one. The new picture is starting to blink one time as a transition and the main transition is as long as before. I tried something like :duration - what I've found in the Vue Doc, but this haven't worked out well :/